# WPF two-way binding to static properties

Tags: c#, wpf, two-way-binding

I'm currently having problems with two-way binding in WPF 4.6.1. It simply doesn't work, I used this example.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/binding-static-properties-in-wpf-4-5/

My project has two windows (a numerical keypad that opens up when a TextBlock is pressed on the first window and a form where data is displayed). It also has a static class that holds the information entered on the virtual keypad.

here is the  TextBox that opens up the Keypad

```
<TextBlock Margin="5 10 0 10" x:Name="submittedQty" Background="PaleVioletRed" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=(local:TemporaryData.SubmittedQuantity), Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" MouseLeftButtonDown="submittedQty_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

Here is my static class holding the information.

```
static class TemporaryData //Static Class
{
    private static string _SubmittedQuantity;
    private static string _ConfirmedQuantity;

    public static event EventHandler QuantityChanged;

    public static string SubmittedQuantity {
        get => _SubmittedQuantity;
        set
        {
            if (value != _SubmittedQuantity)
            {
                _SubmittedQuantity = value;
                if (QuantityChanged != null)
                    QuantityChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            }

        }
    }

    public static string ConfirmedQuantity {
        get => _ConfirmedQuantity;
        set
        {
            if (value != _ConfirmedQuantity)
            {
                _ConfirmedQuantity = value;
                if (QuantityChanged != null)
                {
                    QuantityChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Upon pressing OK on my virtual numeric keypad I execute this method:

```
    private void okBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        models.TemporaryData.ConfirmedQuantity = typedTextTxtBox.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
```

running the debugger I noticed that when my value is updated on the virtual keypad the line

```
if (QuantityChanged != null)
```

is skipped because QuantityChanged is null.

Can anyone let me know why it doesn't the textblock update when the value of the static class changes?

Thanks

---

After following the suggestions of Clemens I updated my code as follows:

**UPDATE**
XML

```
<TextBlock Margin="5 10 0 10" x:Name="submittedQty" Background="PaleVioletRed" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=(local:TemporaryData.SubmittedQuantity)}" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" MouseLeftButtonDown="submittedQty_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

static class

```
static class TemporaryData
    {
        private static string _SubmittedQuantity;
        private static string _ConfirmedQuantity;

        //public static event EventHandler QuantityChanged;
        public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;

        public static string SubmittedQuantity {
            get => _SubmittedQuantity;
            set
            {
                if (value != _SubmittedQuantity)
                {
                    _SubmittedQuantity = value;
                    StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null,
                        new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SubmittedQuantity)));
                }

            }
        }

        public static string ConfirmedQuantity {
            get => _ConfirmedQuantity;
            set
            {
                if (value != _ConfirmedQuantity)
                {
                    _ConfirmedQuantity = value;
                    StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null,
                        new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ConfirmedQuantity)));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: *Instead* of trying to bind to static properties, use a singleton object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and bind to its properties. Simply setting the DataContext of the form will load all properties. Simply modifying one property and raising the NotifyPropertyChanged event will update all forms that bind to it

Comment: BTW when you use *binding* you *don't* need to set the property from the textbox value. That's what *two-way* binding is for. The property will be updated automatically

Comment: I'm sure you are getting an intellisense warning, but you can change the `if (QuantityChanged != nul)...` if block to just `QuantityChanged?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);` The other issue is that you should be using `INotifyPropertyChanged` but you may have to change to a singleton pattern instead of a static-class.

Comment: Who is subscribing to the `QuantityChanged` event?

Comment: Are you able to set a two way binding on a text block? How do you set a text block via the UI?

Comment: My project namespace is RobotSimple, models is the folder containing certain models of the project and TemporaryData is a certain model.

Comment: models is not a namespace it is RobotSimple like such  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RobotSimple.models"

Comment: It's also called a namespace. But `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RobotSimple.models"` should be ok.

Comment: @Clemens Say, do you have a project where your implementation worked?

Comment: @Clemens, I modified the code you submitted, nameof(SubmittedQuantity) didn't work for me, I entered "SubmittedQuantity" instead and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QuantityChanged` event only works for the `Quantity` property.

In order to notify about a changed value of the `SubmittedQuantity` property there should be a `SubmittedQuantityChanged` event:

```
public static event EventHandler SubmittedQuantityChanged;

public static string SubmittedQuantity
{
    get => _SubmittedQuantity;
    set
    {
        if (value != _SubmittedQuantity)
        {
            _SubmittedQuantity = value;
            SubmittedQuantityChanged?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

---

IMO a better alternative would be to use a common property changed event for all static properties:

```
public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

public static string SubmittedQuantity
{
    get => _SubmittedQuantity;
    set
    {
        if (value != _SubmittedQuantity)
        {
            _SubmittedQuantity = value;
            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SubmittedQuantity)));
        }
    }
}
```

See [What's New in WPF Version 4.5 - Binding to static properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/whats-new#binding-to-static-properties) for details.

Comment: Can you check the textblock xml? I think it is incorrect.

Comment: Check what? You probably wanted to use a TextBox? Otherwise `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: <TextBlock Margin="5 10 0 10" x:Name="submittedQty" Background="PaleVioletRed" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=(local:TemporaryData.SubmittedQuantity), Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" MouseLeftButtonDown="submittedQty_MouseLeftButtonDown"/> This is the textblock I use to display the information on the different window

Comment: Please don't post XAML in comments. It's unreadable. I have also already seen that line. Explain what do you think might be wrong with it.

Comment: @MiguelRosales How exactly does that TextBlock get set via the UI? I feel like you're just using the textblock to display the values from the data context. So remove your 2 way binding.

Comment: @Clemens Sorry, just wondering if my binding is alright, I've made the changes and your answer is sound but the binding does not occur.

Comment: Anyway, the Binding itself is ok. Except that Mode and UpdateSourceTrigger have no effect and hence are redundant.

Comment: @Wbuck I'm working with two Windows a numeric keypad and a form that display data. The static variable value is set on the virtual numeric keypad

Comment: @MiguelRosales Is the TemporaryData class located in the correct namespace, i.e. the one referenced by `local`?

Comment: @Clemens, yes, I made sure of that.